# Задержка при запуске приложения

Tags: android

Пишу приложение. Во время запуска (клацаем на лаунчер) я наблюдаю небольшую задержку до отображения моей разметки. Белый фон, statusbar и navbar согласно теме окрашиваются, но БЕЛЫЙ ФОН. Небольшая задержка и появляются мои логотип, прогресс бар и градиент. Можно ли как-то вылечить эту задержку?

P.S: Во многих приложениях есть такая же задержка, а в некоторых нет, т.е я нажал и сразу вижу фон, логотип и т.д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Небольшая задержка связана с тем, что загружается xml файл, необходимые ресурсы, производятся необходимые вычисления и.т.д, и когда всё завершено, пользователю отображается готовое activity.

Вам нужно создать легковесную activity, с минимум ресурсов и указать её как стартовую

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

После чего в `onCreate` вызываем Intent, которое вызовет нужное activity.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Вот [источник](https://habr.com/ru/post/312516/) и которого я черпал информацию.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли